# algebraic expression of vectors

Tags: calculus

let $u,v$ be any n-dimensional vectors with $||u||=5$,$||v||=6$, and $||2u-7v||=\frac 18$, then $||7u+3v||=$

I really don't know where should I start, I tried to find the angel between u and v, but I could not .

How to solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

Use parallelogram law of vector addition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelogram_law

Answer (score 0):

Square all the equations. The first tells you $\|u\|^2$; the second, $\|v\|^2$; then you can use the 3rd (don't forget the distributive law for dot products) to get $u\cdot v$, and you'll have everything you need to answer the question.